# What does 'c' mean in Bash commands like args and grep?

Tags: bash, grep, xargs

```
echo "^[$*]*[$5][$*]*$" |xargs -I c grep -i c words| grep -i ".....*"| grep -
iv "...........*"| sort -f >list
```

Can anyone tell me what the `c` means after xarg and grep?

important note: `words` is a document containing words

Comment: did you read the [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) ?

Comment: In this case it contains the string `^[$*]*[$5][$*]*$`. Read the manpage and search for `-I`, the replace-str option.

Comment: This has nothing do with the manual. How can I possible research/know what 'c' means if it has no meaning bound to a command? I'm asking what c does on its own. I can google the meaning of a '|' pipe, but no way in the world 'c'

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xargs.1.html) for `xargs`:

> **-I** *replace-str*
>
> Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with  names  read  from  standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do not terminate input items; instead  the  separator  is  the  newline character. Implies `-x` and `-L1`.

So `xargs -I c grep -i c words` will replace `c` (the argument of `-I`) with what's read from standard input, in this case `^[`<positional_args_here>`]*[`<5th_positional_arg_here>`][`<positional_args_here>`]*$`. (The shell will replace `$*` and `$5` in the quoted string with the positional arguments and the 5th positional argument respectively.)